# visual studio 2013 image menu missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am "attempting" to use the image editor in Visual Studio 2013 to fix a gif file.  The "documentation" references an image menu which is missing.  I am also attempting to set the foreground and background colors.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image editor has been replaced in VS2013, it no longer uses a dedicated menu.  So whatever documentation you are using is surely outdated.  The VS2013 specific documentation [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.Graphics.ImageEditor%29;k%28vs.graphics%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true).

Pick, say, the Pen tool from the toolbar.  The Properties window lets you set the fore- and background colors.